# Adding Execute (@query) in function error 'incorrect syntax near execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to create a function in SQL Server 2005 that returns a table which the query is passing from my program...

But when I create that function with this script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_test (@source varchar(255))  
RETURNS TABLE AS  
RETURN
    EXECUTE (@source)
```

The script is showing error message

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword "EXECUTE`*

Comment: mssql?...mysql..? oracle..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly correct - you're not allowed to execute arbitrary SQL as part of an inline [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

```
--Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax 
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS TABLE
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]
[ ; ]
```

If you *need*(*) to have a facility to pass arbitrary SQL into a SQL Server object and have it execute it, use a stored procedure rather than a function. Functions are not meant to alter the state of the database, but arbitrary SQL can do... arbitrary things.

---

(*)You don't.

---

As a procedure, it would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (@source varchar(255))  
AS
    EXECUTE (@source)
```

But as is probably evident at this point - if you want to execute arbitrary SQL stored as strings, you may as well just directly call `EXECUTE` on them. That's part of what I was alluding to when I put my (*) in. The other part is - why send it in a string variable to the server at all - why not just send the SQL you want to execute, if you're going to run arbitrary SQL on the server anyway.

Comment: i'm sorry i dont know what should i do if i use stored procedure ,  can u tell me how to use such a thing from stored procedure.. ?

Comment: it's because i try to create dynamic function / stored procedure, so i create it..
and thank you for ur answer,  it's works.. :)